# Fade Out/In when ViewModel Changes

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contentpresenter

My WPF application's main window has a title bar/navigation area that persists for the lifetime of the application, and then there's the workspace area where most of the user interaction takes place. (It's all coded in the spirit of the MVVM pattern, and I might have an excessive aversion to code-behind :/ )  This workspace area is just a `ContentPresenter`, and it's content is bound to a `MainWindowViewModel`'s property of type `ISomeArbitraryVMInterface`.  In my code, this property is updated by raising a `DomainEvent` from wherever.

Having said all of that, when the `DomainEvent` is fired and the Content of the `ContentPresenter` is changed, I'd like the `ContentPresenter` to change its opacity via an animation--From the users perspective, I want it to look as if the current view fades out, the `ContentPresenter` updates with the new `ISomeArbitraryVMInterface`, then the new View corresponding to the new `ISomeArbitraryVMInterface` fades in.

My first thought was to have the ViewModel fire off an event whenever the Content property changes which I then realized I've already done with my `DomainEvent` implementation, but then I couldn't think of a way to make the View "listen" to the event and then fade-out/update/fade-in synchronously.  Any insights into solving this type of problem would be much appreciated.  If there's an elegant solution to be had, I'll post some code-snippets for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AnimatedTransition is what you might be after:

- http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/04/25/orchestrating-animated-transitions-between-view-and-viewmodel/

Alternatively, you might be able to roll your own with the Visual State Manager and some Behaviours to trigger on your DomainEvent, go to the different fade states.

Some other answers:

- [Proper way in MVVM to drive visual states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063808/proper-way-in-mvvm-to-drive-visual-states)
- [Binding [VisualStateManager] view state to a MVVM viewmodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002046/binding-visualstatemanager-view-state-to-a-mvvm-viewmodel)

Comment: Good article--the AnimatedTransition is exactly what I was looking for.